# Adding Submenu-Items using BlackBerry WebWorks?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

Adding Menu Items using the BlackBerry WebWorks SDK is well documented.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Adding-Menu-Items-using-the-BlackBerry-WebWorks-SDK/ta-p/516885

My Question how to add a Submenu-Item?

Creating a submenu is documented only for developing UIApplication

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/Submenus_6_0_1133451_11.jsp#BP_Implementing_submenus_6_0_1133452_11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 
  -

That cannot be done in WebWorks with the available API's, however, you could always create a custom extension if it's something that you really need for your application.

Check-out this documentation if you're interested: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/using_javascript_extensions_1866976_11.html